# R: grouped bar plot every x rows

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I have a dataframe like this:

```
S_ID <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
V_ID <- c(5,5,5,5,8,8,8,8)
T_ID <- c("A","A","B","B","A","A","B","B")
marker1 <- c("+","-","+", "-", "+", "-","+", "-")
marker2 <- c("-","-","-", "-", "-", "-","-", "-")
value <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)

df <- data.frame(S_ID, V_ID,T_ID,marker1, marker2, value)
```

[image]

and I would like to plot a barchart from it. I tried different approaches but just can't get it right. Value should be on the y-axis. x- axis will be 16 labels from : "++++" to "----" coming from columns 4 to 7.
(in minimal example cut don to every 3)

[image]

I have different (usually 4) Tube IDs, so I would like all Tube IDs for "++++" grouped together. I am also adding axis with the axis function for the x-labels

My first approach was  having 16 columns, but as I want to a present the table as well, this option is too confusing and long.

My solution so far includes a plot, that looks like this:

[image]

as you can see, I get the bars,(the x axis is not aligned well here) but I need the bars grouped and I don't know how to get my table grouped every 16 rows.

I am very thankful for any help!

Comment: hope the minimal example works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library('ggplot2')
df1$grp <- factor( with(df1, paste( marker1, marker2, sep = '\n' ) ) )
ggplot(data = df1, mapping = aes( x = grp, y = value, color = T_ID, fill = T_ID)) +
  geom_bar( stat = 'identity', position =  position_dodge(width=0.55), width = 0.5) + 
  theme( axis.text.x = element_text( angle = 0 )) +
  xlab( label = 'Markers' ) + 
  ylab( label = 'Effect' )
```

[image]

with markers in the axis

```
df1$grp <- factor( with(df1, paste( paste('marker1: ', marker1, sep = ''),
                                    paste('marker2: ', marker1, sep = ''),
                                    sep = '\n' ) ) )
ggplot(data = df1, mapping = aes( x = grp, y = value, color = T_ID, fill = T_ID)) +
  geom_bar( stat = 'identity', position =  position_dodge(width=0.55), width = 0.5) + 
  theme( axis.text.x = element_text( angle = 0 )) +
  xlab( label = 'Markers' ) + 
  ylab( label = 'Effect' )
```

[image]

```
df1$grp <- factor( with(df1, paste( marker1, marker2, sep = '\n' ) ) )
text_markers <- textGrob( paste( 'marker1', 'marker2', sep = '\n' ), gp=gpar(fontsize=8))
p <- ggplot(data = df1, mapping = aes( x = grp, y = value, color = T_ID, fill = T_ID)) +
  geom_bar( stat = 'identity', position =  position_dodge(width=0.55), width = 0.5) + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme( axis.text.x = element_text( angle = 0 )) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,8.5), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  xlab( label = 'Markers' ) + 
  ylab( label = 'Effect' ) + 
  annotation_custom( text_markers, xmin = -Inf, xmax = 0.85, ymin = -Inf, ymax = -1.5 )

gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name == "panel"] <- "off"
grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

**Data:**

```
S_ID <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
V_ID <- c(5,5,5,5,8,8,8,8)
T_ID <- c("A","A","B","B","A","A","B","B")
marker1 <- c("+","-","+", "-", "+", "-","+", "-")
marker2 <- c("-","-","-", "-", "-", "-","-", "-")
value <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
df1 <- data.frame(S_ID, V_ID,T_ID,marker1, marker2, value)
```

Comment: the first one is exactly what I've been looking for. Thank you! There is alway new things when working with R. time difference made it hard to answer right away:-)

Comment: is there a way to add a label for the markers on the very left side to know  from the graph which marker has which value ?

Comment: please have a look at my original post, picture 3. when looking at the graph it would be very helpful to know which marker (cd27, cd38 and there would be many more) represents which line of the label